# Foursquare search venues by category, invalid categoryId error

Tags: api, foursquare

I'm trying to fetch venues for category with id=4bf58dd8d48988d1dd941735 using venues/search endpoint.

venues/search?categoryId=4bf58dd8d48988d1dd941735

After this call I get an error "Invalid categoryId 4bf58dd8d48988d1dd941735"

```
{
  meta: {
    code: 400
    errorType: "param_error"
    errorDetail: "Invalid categoryId 4bf58dd8d48988d1dd941735"
  }
  response: { }
}
```

Does it mean that the given category was removed from foursquare and I should remove it from my application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The full list of valid categories can be accessed by the [venues/categories](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/categories) endpoint. The ID you've given does not appear in it's output, so no, that's not a valid category ID.

Comment: ..but I had this category in my system and it worked. Anyway I'm going to consider this category as deleted on foursquare's side.

Comment: Category list should not be cached for a long time. You need to sync your database values with Foursquare, categories are subject to change.